# Skyrim dragons difficulty

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Hi all got skyrim modded on xbox serisx. Idk what ive done wrong but when i was level 24 i had 2 eldar draagons spawn. Im pretty sure they are not meant to spawn this early. Any ideas what mods can cause this? thanks!

Comment: It'd be quite helpful if we knew what mods you have installed.

Answer (score 4):

Elder Dragons spawn on level 22 and beyond, so no this isn't a bug or something it's working as intended. (But they are supposed to be rare, with their encounter rate peaking at level 36 before slowly fading out in favor of Ancient dragons with at level 50 they become rare again compared to stronger variants)

Probably the idea behind this is that Skyrim throws enemies at you (like giants spawning at level 1) to make you feel weaker, and therefor giving you more of a sense of accomplishment when actually defeating the obstacle thrown at you.